# How to reset the form validation on a create modal?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am not sure what I should do here in this case. When I click on `+ Rule`, I call this fn()

```
showAddRuleModal() {
    this.showAddRule = true

    this.$refs.form.reset()

    //reset form values
    this.ruleName = ''
    this.url = 'https://www.'
    this.urlType = 'Single'

    this.ruleDetails = []

    let ruleDetail = {
        attribute_id: '',
        operator_id: '',
        value: ''
    }

    this.ruleDetails.push(ruleDetail)
}
```

As you can see in the image, I successfully created a rule, and tried to add one more.

[image]

As you can see the other values seems to reset but my `ruleName` input detected as an error even if I reset `this.$refs.form.reset()`

How can I stop this ?

---

## Note

If I add a space to the default value

```
this.ruleName = ' '
```

that error is gone, but now, my form ruleName contains a space.
Works, but it's not great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the modal is opened use this:

```js
this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
```

this should reset the validation. [documentation example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#validation-with-submit-26-clear)